# WSO2 EI 6.6.0 hal_json Format Issue

Tags: wso2, drupal-8, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

6.0 to call a Drupal 8 RESTful web service endpoint which returns the response in hal_json format. I have never come across this format before but this is what the Drupal 8 response is in. The Content-Type is "application/hal+json". For more information, this is the Drupal 8 link - https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/3-post-for-creating-content-entities

I'm using a property mediator to convert the response from hal_json format to XML but I'm getting the below error:

**OMException in getSOAPBuilder org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'**

I searched online for this error and found that this type of error usually occurs when the API response is in a format that is not enabled in WSO2 (it needs to be enabled in the axis2.xml file). Can anyone please tell me what property I need to add to my axis2.xml file? I think is needs to be a message formatter and builder property.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with the JSON message type specified. But if it is a valid JSON message you can define a JsonStreamBuilder builder for this message type. The message builder can be defined as follows in the axis2.xml file under messageBuilders in [EI_HOME]/conf/axis2 directory

```
<messageBuilders>
..
<messageBuilder contentType="application/hal+json"                                   
  class="org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
..
</messageBuilders>
```

After modifying the axis2.xml you need to perform a server restart in order for this to take effect.